# How do capacitors discharge?

Tags: electric-circuits, capacitance

I'm having some trouble understanding how capacitors work. I can visualize how a capacitor would charge up and how current "flows" through it.

But I don't really understand the concept of the discharge. I gather that you simply get rid of the accumulated charge on the plates, and it happens relatively fast. But how? Do you get a spark?

And on top of that, in a simple circuit with the battery, a capacitor and a light bulb connected in series, how does the discharge of the capacitor make a bright flash of the bulb (the typical example of a use of a capacitor).

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, so capacitors allow *current* to flow, but not *electrons* to flow, between the terminals. As a consequence, when they are operational, a density of electrons builds up on one side and a density of missing-electrons builds up on the other side, until the charge on either plate is given by $|Q| = C |V|$ where $C$ is the capacitance and $V$ is the voltage across the junction.

Suppose we have a loop, as you say:

```
  +----[Battery, V1]>----+
  |                      |
===== C                  |
  |                      |
  +----[Light Bulb, R]---+
```

This is a typical RC-circuit; if the voltage across the capacitor starts out as $V_0$ then the voltage as a function of time is:

$ V(t) ~=~ V_1 ~+~ (V_0 - V_1) e^{-t/RC} $

This means that most of the "action" happens over the time scale $R C$ where $R$ is the resistance of the light bulb and $C$ is again the capacitance.

So let's start off with $V_0 = 0$, $V_1 = V^*$ for some special voltage $V^*$. The light bulb will shine some light as the capacitor charges, until the capacitor's electrons are built up enough to "push against the battery"; then $V = V^*$ as $t \rightarrow \infty$.

Once we have reached this steady state, let's disconnect the battery completely and insert a short where the battery *was*. Then it's the same story with $V_0 = V^*$ and $V_1 = 0$. Current flows *backwards* across the light bulb, which would also light it up.

**You do not get a spark unless the capacitor breaks.** Very important. The electrons *do not jump the gap*. They return to the other side by going back the way they came.

Comment: Spark unless capacitor breaks?  Not sure about that.  I used to have a big oil filled capacitor back in the 1960s that I had in my power supply for a linear amplifier I built (ham radio).  I could charge up this capacitor and then disconnect the capacitor and put a huge screw driver across the terminals.  Not only does this cause a spark but on several occasions it just melted the tip of the screw driver.  This capacitor had enough charge that I could dead short the capacitor and then do it again (without intervening charge up) and get more sparks.

Comment: I think what Chris was more or so getting at is that a capacitor that allows current to flow directly like that is a malfunctioning capacitor. A lot of electronics rely on the fact that the buildup of charge on a capacitor goes unsatiated.

Comment: Right. I don't mean that the capacitor itself cannot cause sparks, I mean that a spark *inside the capacitor* (i.e. through the dielectric material inside the capacitor) usually destroys the capacitor and sounds like a loud "pop". The electric energy of the capacitor can definitely cause sparks if you hold the terminals together -- for that matter, so can batteries.

Comment: So the capacitor doesn't discharge until the current drops to zero (battery is disconnected)?

Answer (score 0):

> I gather that you simply get rid of the accumulated charge on the
>   plates, and it happens relatively fast.

If a capacitor is discharging, current *exits* the more positive terminal rather than *entering*.  That's really all there is to it.

When current *enters* the more positive terminal, power is *delivered* to the capacitor and, thus, the stored energy *increases*.

When current *exits* the more positive terminal, power is *supplied* by the capacitor and, thus, the stored energy *decreases*.

This does not need to occur quickly.  If you connect a resistor with resistance $R$ across a charged (and otherwise unconnected) capacitor with capacitance $C$, the time required to discharge the capacitor to less than 1% of its initial charge is about $t = 5RC$.

For example, let $R = 1\mathrm{k\Omega}$ and $C = 1\mathrm{\mu F}$.  The time required to discharge the capacitor is

$$t_D = 5\cdot 1\mathrm{k\Omega}\cdot1\mathrm{\mu F} = 5\mathrm{ms}$$